# Matplotlib or Sympy - Implicit inequalities or relations

Tags: matplotlib, sympy

Can matplotlib draw relations like `x^2+y^2<=2` in blue and then `x^2+y^2<=1+0.5*sin((x^3+y^3)*2pi)` in red ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at `plot_implicit` in [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html).

```
>>> from sympy import plot_implicit, sin, symbols, pi
>>> x, y = symbols('x y')
>>> my_plot = plot_implicit(x**2 + y**2 <= 1 + 0.5 * sin((x**3 + y**3) * 2 * pi))
```

[image]